# Clone last html elements with autoincremented id using javascript

Tags: javascript

Could you please guide me how to clone last html elements using JavaScript only. I want to clone  with auto incremented id  throughout all. But I am seeing  is cloning. I am expecting to get in this case . Am I able to explain you?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aucv3637/3/

```js
    var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var original = document.getElementById('repeat');
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "repeat" + ++i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldName"]')[0].id = "fieldName" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldType"]')[0].id = "fieldType" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[name="mandatory"]')[0].name = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="mandatory"]')[0].id = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.children[2].children[0].name = "mandatory" + i;

  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
};
```

```html
    <table>
<tbody id="fieldsContent">                     
<tr id="repeat">                                                 <td><input type="text" id="fieldName"></td>                         <td>
<select name="fieldType" id="fieldType">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option>
<option value="String">String</option><option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>                        
</td>                         
<td><input type="checkbox" id="mandatory" name="mandatory">                                             </td>                                                                      </tr>                        
<tr id="repeat1">                                                 <td><input type="text" id="fieldName1"></td>                         <td>                            
<select name="fieldType" id="fieldType1">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option>
<option value="String">String</option>
<option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>                        
</td>                         
<td>                            
<input type="checkbox" id="mandatory1" name="mandatory1">                                                    </td>                                                                      </tr>
<tr id="repeat2">                                                 <td><input type="text" id="fieldName2"></td>                         <td>                            <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType2">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option><option value="String">String</option>
<option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>                        
</td>                         
<td>                            
<input type="checkbox" id="mandatory2" name="mandatory2">                                                    </td>                                                                      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="start" name="start" onclick="myFunction()">
  <span>Add</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I have updated my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aucv3637/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code, [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8os1jqn/3/)

- `i` not initialized
- using `lastChild` instead of the element itself.
- Not wrapping `myFunction` in `head`.

Change to

```
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var original = document.getElementById('repeat');
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "repeat" + ++i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldName"]')[0].id = "fieldName" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="fieldType"]')[0].id = "fieldType" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[name="mandatory"]')[0].name = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('[id="mandatory"]')[0].id = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.children[2].children[0].name = "mandatory" + i;

  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
};
```

**Edit**

You need to use **starts-with id selector** in `querySelector` and `last-child`

```
function myFunction() {
  var original = document.querySelector('tr[id^="repeat"]:last-child');
  var match = original.id.match(/\d+$/g);
  var idCounter = !!match ? +match[0] : 0;
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  var i = (idCounter + 1);
  clone.id = "repeat" + i;
  console.log(clone);
  clone.querySelector('[id^="fieldName"]').id = "fieldName" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[id^="fieldType"]').id = "fieldType" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[name^="mandatory"]').name = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[id^="mandatory"]').id = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.children[2].children[0].name = "mandatory" + i;

  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
};
```

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var original = document.querySelector('tr[id^="repeat"]:last-child');
  var match = original.id.match(/\d+$/g);
  var idCounter = !!match ? +match[0] : 0;
  console.log(idCounter);
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  var i = (idCounter + 1);
  clone.id = "repeat" + i;
  console.log(clone);
  clone.querySelector('[id^="fieldName"]').id = "fieldName" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[id^="fieldType"]').id = "fieldType" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[name^="mandatory"]').name = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.querySelector('[id^="mandatory"]').id = "mandatory" + i;
  clone.children[2].children[0].name = "mandatory" + i;

  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="fieldsContent">
    <tr id="repeat">
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldName"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option>
<option value="String">String</option><option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="mandatory" name="mandatory"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="repeat1">
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldName1"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType1">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option>
<option value="String">String</option>
<option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mandatory1" name="mandatory1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="repeat2">
      <td><input type="text" id="fieldName2"></td>
      <td> <select name="fieldType" id="fieldType2">                                                                                            <option value="Date">Date</option><option value="String">String</option>
<option value="Integer">Integer</option>
<option value="IA5String">IA5String</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mandatory2" name="mandatory2"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="start" name="start" onclick="myFunction()">
  <span>Add</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting me. But my problem is not solved when getting multiple <tr id="repeat"> and that is why I want to clone last html elements.

Comment: You are getting an element by id, you will only get one element. There is no last-element when you are getting only one element as result.

Comment: I am unable to find out the error. Could you guide me in my last fiddle.

Comment: Hi dear, finally I updated my fiddle. But still clone is performing from 1st one, not the last one. Am I able to understand you? Please check my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aucv3637/3/

Comment: Hello dear, could you please help me to resolve this. In case of jsfiddle.net/aucv3637/3 , clone is performing by taking <tr id="repeat"> and hence again I am getting <tr id="repeat1">. I am expecting to get <tr id=repeat3>. Am I able to explain you?

Comment: Ok, gimme some time

Comment: I am unable to access fiddles from my system... can you add a working snippet in your question itself?

Comment: @Soma I have shared a working example. please have a look.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am trying to implement your code in my coding section and let you inform about the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working when multiple <tr> exist, but when only one <tr id="repeat"> exists then this solution is not working. Could you please look into this once again. here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/62cc6ww8/1/

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your solution works for me. You are great.